Azure Service Bus - Message from Sender being enqueued twice
I'm relatively new to Azure Service Bus, and message queues in general. While familiarising myself, I've run into something that I initially thought was something clunky I had done, but am becoming increasingly confused by as I try to figure out the root cause.
In a very simple app, I have an endpoint that passes some hard-coded details to a generic "queue this message" service class:
public class TestFunction(IEventBusService eventBusService)
{
    [Function("TestFunction")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get")] HttpRequestData req)
    {
        try
        {
            await eventBusService.SendAsync(new TestObject { Message = "Message for service bus", SentAtDateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow }, Queues.Test);

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            await response.WriteAsJsonAsync("Message successfully published to service bus", "application/json");
            return response;
        }
        catch (ServiceBusOperationFailedException)
        {
            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            await response.WriteAsJsonAsync("Unable to publish message to service bus", "application/json");
            return response;
        }
    }
}

public class TestObject
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset SentAtDateTimeOffset { get; set; }
}

The method in question looks like this:
public class EventBusService(ServiceBusClient serviceBusClient) : IEventBusService
{
    public async Task SendAsync<T>(T dataToSend, string sendTo, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        ValidateParams(dataToSend, sendTo);

        var serviceBusSender = serviceBusClient.CreateSender(sendTo);
        var messageJson = new ServiceBusMessage(JsonSerializer.Serialize(dataToSend));

        try
        {
            await serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(messageJson, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceBusOperationFailedException($"Unable to publish message to '{sendTo}'.", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            await serviceBusSender.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }

    private void ValidateParams<T>(T dataToSend, string sendTo)
    {
        if (dataToSend is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataToSend));

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sendTo))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sendTo));
    }
}

All seems straightforward enough.
To verify that this was behaving as expected, I put together a quick test that would call the endpoint...
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Should_OnSuccessfulPublishToEventBus_ReceiveConfirmationMessage()
    {
        // Arrange
        var testFunction = new TestFunction(EventBusHelper.CreateService());

        var mockFunctionContext = EventBusHelper.GetMockFunctionContext();

        //Act
        var response = await testFunction.Run(new TestHttpRequestData(mockFunctionContext));

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(response);
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);

        response.Body.Position = 0;
        using var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.Body);
        var responseBody = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

        Assert.AreEqual("\"Message successfully published to service bus\"", responseBody);
    }

...and check the result using Service Bus Explorer.
However, when I looked at the queued messages, I could see that the same message had been added to the queue twice. This has since happened every time I've run the test.
Pre test run:

Post test run:

Based on my code above, is there any reason this is happening? I've debugged and made sure the endpoint is only being hit once, so I can only think that it's some intricacy of message queueing that I'm ignorant to. Any help or advice is appreciated!
Thanks,
Mark

What do you see if you closely inspect those two messages (payload and system properties)? Could you post the two side by side?


Azure Service Bus - Message from Sender being enqueued twice

There may be some reasons such as Host is sending message concurrently, or you might have set the retry policy, due to which it is sending data twice.
One way to prevent is setting the option below while creating the queue:

or below is the code( used DuplicateDetection)  which is sending message only once:
Function1.cs:
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp170
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ServiceBusClient rith_sbc;
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> r_log;
        public Function1(ServiceBusClient sbc, ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            rith_sbc = sbc;
            r_log = logger;
        }
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
        {
            r_log.LogInformation("Hello, code is started executing");
            var rith_obj = new { Message = "Secret", Time = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow };
            var mid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var r_sen = rith_sbc.CreateSender("rithqueue");
            var rith_msg = new ServiceBusMessage(JsonSerializer.Serialize(rith_obj))
            {
                MessageId = mid
            };
            await r_sen.SendMessageAsync(rith_msg);
            return new OkObjectResult("Hello Rithwik Bojja, Message is sent to Service Bus Successfully"); 
        }
    }
}

Startup.cs:
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp170.Startup))]

namespace FunctionApp170
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            string rith_cs = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Rith_Service_Bus_Con");
            var rith_ac = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(rith_cs);
            ConfigureQueueAsync(rith_ac).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton(new ServiceBusClient(rith_cs));
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<Function1>();
        }
        private async Task ConfigureQueueAsync(ServiceBusAdministrationClient r_ac)
        {
            var r_q_name = "rithqueue";
            if (!await r_ac.QueueExistsAsync(r_q_name))
            {
                var rith_op = new CreateQueueOptions(r_q_name)
                {
                    RequiresDuplicateDetection = true,
                    DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
                };
                await r_ac.CreateQueueAsync(rith_op);
            }
        }
    }
}

local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "Rith_Service_Bus_Con": "Endpoint=sb://rithwik.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=eu6XXSQ="
  }
}

Output:


Using above code no twice enqueuing is taking place.
